# How to populate an Ext.data.TreeStore without children or leaf information?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, gridpanel, treepanel

I have a service that returns an array of Things. A Thing simply has an `id` and a `name`.

I want to load these into an `Ext.tree.Panel`. For now, I've defined a data store that mimics a typical response from the service. You can play with a demo JSFiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2nqAh/7/).

Code included below as well:

```
Ext.define('Thing', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'name'],
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', {
    model: 'Thing',

    // example service response (in reality, this would be JSON)
    root: {
        children: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Thing 1',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Thing 2',
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Thing 3',
            },
        ],
    },

    listeners: {
        append: function(thisNode, newChildNode, index, eOpts) {
            if( !newChildNode.isRoot() ) {
                newChildNode.set('text', newChildNode.get('name'));
            }
        },
    },
});

Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
});
```

As you can see, the service only returns a Thing's `id` and `name`, no tree node information like `children` or `leaf`, which is what an `Ext.data.TreeStore` normally expects.

I simply cannot change what the service returns as a response. I like that I can call the service and get a flat array of Things, without extraneous tree node information. There are many apps talking to this service that simply do not need such data, and I don't have permission from the powers-that-be to change it.

Unfortunately, without the `children` element defined for each Thing in the response, Ext raises the following error when I attempt to expand a node (you can produce this yourself in the JSFiddle):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined
```

**So, my question is:** how can I avoid having to send back `children` (or `leaf`) in my response and resolve this error? I'd simply like my Things to be loaded into the tree and to be expandable (yes, they can't be leaves).

Answer (score 0):

Add those information by yourself!

Little example (You easily can try it in the console from your browser):

```
a = {b:23};
a.c = 25;
//a is now the same like {b:23, c:25}
```

In the afterRequest-method of the store you can for example do following:

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',

    url: 'xxx',

    listeners: {
        exception: function(proxy, response, options) {
            //error case
        }
    },

    afterRequest: function(request, success) {
        var resText = request.operation.response.responseText,
            allThings = Ext.decode(resText),  //Decodes (parses) a JSON string to an object
            things = allThins.children,       //Now we have an object an we can do what we want...
            length = things.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            things[i].leaf = true;
            things[i].expanded = true;
        }

        this.setRootNode(allThings); 
    }
}
```

This is just some pseudo-code, but it should work! 
Set a **debugger Statement** ([Link](http://blog.katworksgames.com/2012/09/27/debugger-statement-makes-javascript-development-easier/)) and see what you are really getting back!

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might try iterating over your response store and creating children nodes.
Then append your children to your root node

```
store.each(function(rec) {  
  var childNode ;  
  //Create a new object and set it as a leaf node (leaf: true)  
  childNode = Ext.create('Model_Name', {  
       id: rec.data.id,  
       name: rec.data.name,
       text : rec.data.name,  
       leaf : true,  
  });  
  // add/append this object to your root node  
  treepanel.getRootNode().appendChild(childNode );  
 });
```

Check [this link](http://atechiediary.blogspot.in/2013/06/extjs-how-to-create-static-and-dynamic.html) for more details